speeding up cosine similarity
I am trying to find the similarity between many molecules and a single protein, using their molecular representation. The molecular representation of these elements are obtained as follows:

One form rdkit library mol = rdkit.Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
The other is read from a file.

Each mol representation is a list of size 1024.
There are 600,000 molecules but only a single protein
The process of calculating the cosine similarity, depicted here, is taking an excruciatingly long time, even after parallelizing the process across the 4 CPUs available (pool.map() is slower, but I need to preserve order across threads).
I tried using GPUs but none of the processes seem to be optimized for GPU usage as I can only see CPU activity and zero GPU utilization.
The code provided here is only running the first 10,000 and still taking over 2 hours.
I am looking for suggestion on how to improve the speed of processing.
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import rdkit
from rdkit import Chem

# Function to compute chemical similarity
def compute_similarity(mol1, mol2):
    if mol1 is not None and mol2 is not None:
        fp1 = Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol1)
        fp2 = Chem.RDKFingerprint(mol2)
        similarity = cosine_similarity([fp1], [fp2])[0][0]
        return similarity
    else:
        return None

def compute_similarity_wrapper(args):
    return compute_similarity(*args)

# The calculation for similarity takes too long. Let's parallelize it
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

molecule_mols_subset = molecule_mols[:10_000]

# Get the number of available processors
num_processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(f" {num_processors} CPUs ---- available for parallel processing")

# Use multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize the computation
# Use the "map" function to preserve the order after parallel computing.
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processors) as pool:
    sims = pool.map(compute_similarity_wrapper, [(mol, alb_mol) for mol in molecule_mols_subset])

sims[:10]


Did you consider run over a cluster with dask or having a look at rapids? https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/blob/d2099b8ffc74163ca7bdca94dbbeb596081acf65/python/cuml/metrics/pairwise_distances.pyx#L140

What makes you think the bottleneck is in the cosine_simularity function rather than in the RDKFingerprint function? (Not a rethorical question though it seems very unlikely to me that sklearn is the culprit. The fingerprint function seems pretty heavy-weight to me.) An easy way to optimize may be to calculate at least the fingerprint of alb_mol outside of the cos wrapper function.

Out of curiosity: Do the RDKfingerprints preserve a distance/similarity metric between the molecules?

I took a quick look at the rdkit API, and it turns out that it already includes a DataStructs.CosineSimularity function. Using that function gives the same result as sklearn cosine_simularity (as could be expected) and is about 200x as fast (as also could be expected, since it can use its own datastructs without having to do multiple implicit conversions). So, using this and the earlier trick (prev comment) should give you a speed up of perhaps >= 400x.

Last bit of unsollicited advise :) Imo it's a waste of time and resources to try to use parallellization or to experiment with other libs like dask, if you don't know what the actual bottlenecks in your algorithm are and if you haven't first optimized the non-distributed computation.

@mudskipper - Thank you most kindly for looking into this question and the many wonderful suggestions. I now have two viable avenues to pursue. I am sure one will offer an excellent alternative to what I have now.
I also agree strongly with you on profiling the code to pin point the bottlenecks. In my case your sharp eye spotted another excellent area where the actual bottleneck may lie. Thank you for that as well.
